# Site to Site VPN 4G/5G

Tags: vpn, site-to-site-vpn, watchguard

We have just set up a new site where internet is currently unavailable so we are using 4G/5G internet which we are unable to get a static IP address for. We use WatchGuard devices for Branch Office VPN but you need a static address for this it appears. Does anyone know of any hardware devices that will allow us to have a site to site VPN for the entire network? The new site doesn't have any servers etc to use.

Thanks for any assistance :)

Cheers

Comment: More or less any VPN protocol will work. However, we don't do product recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

The [fine manual](https://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/help-center/en-US/Content/en-US/Fireware/bovpn/manual/bovpn_manual_about_c.html) seems to say that a static IP-address is **not** a requirement for a branch office VPN:

> ...
> You must know whether the IP address assigned to the other VPN device is static or dynamic. ***If the other VPN device has a dynamic IP address and uses dynamic DNS***, you can specify the domain name of that device. If ***the other device does not use dynamic DNS***, that device can send any non-resolvable domain string if it is the initiator. For dynamic endpoints, you must use either IKEv1 Aggressive Mode or IKEv2 (recommended).
> ...